# I'm working on a online voting system, I want to update the 'status' in my database every time the user vote, how can I do it?

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

**Table name = user**

| id | name | username | password | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | voter1 | voter1 | password1 | Unvoted |
| 2 | voter2 | voter1 | password2 | Unvoted |

I tried

UPDATE users SET status='Voted' Where

idk what to put in  "where"

Comment: Normally it would be: `UPDATE user SET status = 'Voted' WHERE id = ?`. You should have found the `id` before with the `username` and `password`. Don't forgot to use parameter binding when you execute the queries. Also note that, according to you, the table is called `user` and not `users`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the voter's ID in the `WHERE` clause to uniquely identify who voted.
This will likely be set in your `PHP` as a session variable.

```sql
UPDATE user 
SET status = 'Voted' 
WHERE id = $userID
```

You should have your PHP look like this (for security using prepared statements and variable binding):

```php
// prepare and bind
$statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE user SET status = 'Voted' WHERE id = ?");
$statement->bind_param("i", $userID);
```